# Каким образом можно вывести выделенные элементы?

Tags: html

[image: Образец таблицы.]

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    </td>
    <td>256</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>0xbad</i></td>
    <td>
      <h3>ASP.NET</h3>
    </td>
    <td align="center">0
      <hr>O
      <hr><input type="radio" checked="checked">
      <hr><a href="https://www.google.ru">google.ru</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><input type="submit" value="4"><input type="submit" value="8"><input type="submit" value="15"><input type="submit" value="16"><input type="submit" value="23"><input type="submit" value="42"></td>
    </p>
    <td><a href="http://127.0.0.1">127.0.0.1</a></td>
    <td>Eyjafjallajokull</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> <input type="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> <input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>asp.net</td>
    <td>=====&gt&gt&gt &lt&lt&lt=====</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" checked="checked"><input type="radio" checked="checked"><input type="radio" checked="checked"><input type="radio" checked="checked"><input type="radio"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5>ASP.NET</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr with="30px">
    <td>first line second line</td>
    <td>first line second line</td>
    <td>first line second line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм..

Треугольники из `radio`.

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <center>
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
      </center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <br>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Треугольник вправо из `radio`

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio"><br>
      <input type="radio">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Расположение строк

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr valign="middle">
    <td>
      <p>first line</p>
      <p>second line</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>first line</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>second line</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>first line</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>second line</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```